# Summation of floor of harmonic progression multiply with i : $\sum_{i=2}^n i\cdot\lfloor\frac ni\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, harmonic-analysis

Summation of floor of harmonic progression multiply with $i$:

> $$\sum_{i=2}^n i\cdot\left\lfloor\frac ni\right\rfloor$$

This actually from a programming question. This formula is required to compute solution faster. But I can't figure out this solution.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Maybe you can ask this at stackoverflow or something?

Comment: Why is the sum started at 2 instead of 1? There would be no problem.

Comment: You can easily get to the asymptotic formula that Peter mentioned, just by following [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266850/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n2-sum-limits-k/3267022#3267022).

Comment: What do you mean by fast? How big is $n$? This kind of "convolution"always reminds me FFT.

Answer (score 3):

This is effectively OEIS sequence [A024916](https://oeis.org/A024916). There seems to be no formula for the terms.

Answer (score 1):

As a continuation of the comment I left (using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266850/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n2-sum-limits-k/3267022#3267022)). Using [division with remainder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266850/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1n2-sum-limits-k/3267022#3267022), if $n=q_ii+r_i$ s.t. $0\leq r_i < i$, then
$$r_i=n \pmod{i}$$
$$q_i=\left \lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right \rfloor$$
$$r_i=n-i\left \lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right \rfloor$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{i=2}^n i\cdot\left\lfloor\frac ni\right\rfloor=
\sum_{i=2}^n (n-r_i)=
n(n-1)-\sum_{i=2}^n r_i =\\
n(n-1)-\sum_{i=2}^n \left(n \pmod{i}\right)$$

I am not sure what do you mean by "faster", but I presume computing $n \pmod{i}$ is faster than $i \cdot ...$ and $\left\lfloor\frac ni\right\rfloor$.

From the same link, it is relatively easy to see that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot\left\lfloor\frac ni\right\rfloor=
n^2-\sum_{i=1}^n \left(n \pmod{i}\right) \sim \\
n^2 - n^2\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)=n^2\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$
as per the [link](https://oeis.org/A024916) suggested by @Peter.