# Number Theory Inequality Proof

Tags: number-theory

For positive integer $n>0 \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $\sigma (1) + \sigma (2) + \cdots + \sigma (n) \leq n^2$.

I tried listing out the first few terms, but it doesn't really help that much. I also tried to simplify each term by splitting it up into prime factors( Note: This is not for all terms) but that didn't yield anything useful.

Comment: @lhf: Ah, you’re right: I was thinking of $\sigma_0(n)$.

Comment: Numerically, it seems to be close to $\pi^2 n^2/12$

Comment: It is close to $n^2\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ [indeed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326430/summation-of-floor-of-harmonic-progression-multiply-with-i-sum-i-2n-i-cdo/3326955#3326955).

Answer (score 2):

You have $$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{d|k} d$$
Rearrange it to $$\sum_{d=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^{n/d} d$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of $n$.  It follows that, for $d≤n$, $d$ appears once in the sum for every integer less than $n$ divisible by $d$.  Thus your sum is equal to $$\sum_{d=1}^n \Big\lfloor \frac  nd\Big \rfloor d<n\sum_{d=1}^n \frac 1d\times d=n\times n=n^2$$